# Don't Put a Needle in Bread? (What is the Taz referring to?)

Tags: minhag, commentaries, bread, shulchan-aruch

The Taz [YD 116:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=) on the last line brings a case that he heard that one should protest putting a needle into bread. What is the Taz referring, to and what exactly is he worried about?

Comment: related? http://today.msnbc.msn.com/id/48209579/ns/travel-news/ -- MSNBC  7/17/2012 - "Authorities investigate needles in airplane sandwiches"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the [Taz](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=) is saying that one should object to feeding a vicious dog a loaf of bread with a needle in it, as a way of disposing of it. Rather, the proper way to kill the dog is with poison. It seems that, according to the Taz, giving the dog a loaf of bread with a needle in it is not, in this instance, a violation of *tzaar baalei chaim* nor of *bal tashchis*. However, it **is** a concern that this will drive the vicious dog mad, and it can be a life-threatening danger to others.

Also, it seems that even some people nowadays think to do this. Consider [this case](http://detroit.cbslocal.com/2012/02/18/man-who-fed-neighbors-dog-needles-pleads-no-contest-in-animals-death/), from Feb 2012:

> A Michigan man who hid needles in meat that was eaten by a neighbor’s dog faces sentencing after pleading no contest to attempted animal killing or torture.

Comment: seems like that's the pshat,thanks.It is it more advice or halahcha?

Comment: Josh, what I am having trouble understanding is, is this independent (and tangentially related, I suppose), or is this a Limud that he is applying to the case at hand? If it's the former, so what? And if it's the latter, huh?

Comment: @SethJ I assumed the same,but I guess not.

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure i understand the question. it seems like it is halacha, and dealing, i suppose, with a somewhat prevalent means of killing vicious animals in the 17th century. (One doesn't advise protest against a random practice that nobody would ever do.) And since the topic turned to killing animals via poison, he turned to cover this case as well. See also my emendation to the answer.